# How to add page numbers?

Tags: page-numbering

I have the number 1 written at the bottom of the first page of my latex document, but none of the other pages have page numbers.  How can I have page numbers on every page ?

Here is what I did:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\title{Rapport de physique: Transformation du travail en chaleur}
\author{computerdummy}
\date{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{computerdummy}
\lhead{Rapport de physique: Transformation \\ du travail en chaleur}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
%
\end{abstract}

\section{But de l'expérience}

%
\section{Théorie}

    \paragraph{Le travail de la force}
%

    \paragraph{L'énergie calorifique}
%
    \paragraph{Comment nous nous en servirons}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can use `fancyhdr` or with KOMA-Script `scrlayer-scrpage`, depending on your used code you did not show us!  Please add a short, **compilable** code to your question showing how you get the first page number ...

Comment: Is there some `\pagestyle{empty}` in your document? Your description leaves a lot of guessing

Comment: `titleps`, which comes with `titlesec` is another possibility.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) The default behaviour of most classes it to add page numbers to (almost all) pages. So please show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that can be used to reproduce your problem. Without such a MWE your problem is either to broad or quiet unclear.

Comment: If the question was a mistake, the best option is to delete it... ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The page where `\maketitle` does its work uses the `plain` page style. On the others, the `fancy` page style is used and you cleared all headers and footers, resetting the left and right header. You didn't set the footer.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{computerdummy}
\fancyhead[L]{Rapport de physique: Transformation \\ du travail en chaleur}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % <--- MISSING
```